# Angular JS ng-options returns "? object:005 ?"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I have searched everywhere and it is hard to tell what i'm doing wrong. I'm trying to populate a select component with values from a controller

My snippet from my controller

```
$scope.sTypes=
[
    {name:'PGD',id:1},
    {name:'MSC',id:2},
    {name:'PHD',id:3},
    {name:'DBA',id:4}
]
$scope.selectedType={};
```

My HTML select

```
<select ng-model="selectedType" ng-option="sType.name for sType in sTypes">
            <option>--- Select Scholarship ---</option>
        </select>
```

What is being rendered

```
<select 
   ng-model="selectedType" 
   ng-option="sType.name for sType in sTypes" 
   class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <option value="? object:005 ?"></option>
        <option value="--- Select Scholarship ---">
    --- Select Scholarship ---
        </option>
</select>
```

Any help will be much appreciated because this is starting to piss me off.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen that exact thing myself, but I've found adding `value=""` to the null select option to work:

```
    <select ng-model="selectedType" ng-option="sType.name for sType in sTypes">
        <option value="">--- Select Scholarship ---</option>
    </select>
```

This will then be the default select option if `ng-model` is null.

So, I would configure the html like above and then initialize `selectedType` like this:

```
$scope.selectedType=null;
```

Comment: Thanks davin. i have fixed it. It was a silly mistake, i was using "ng-option" instead of "ng-options"

Comment: so you should delete this question because if no problem, its not helpful. Cheers :)